# How to get rerunfilecheck warning parsed which is not on a single line

Tags: luatex

Seems a strange question, I can imagine.
I get the following warning in the log file:

```
Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `manualArithInOctave.aux' has changed. Rer
un.
```

As one can see, `Rerun` is split because the name of the file is so long.
Since I write a software checking rerun automatically
and I did not think about line break,
currently my software fails.
This break is the same for all latex compiler.
How would you deal with that?
is it possible to make the line longer?

Currently I help myself checking for

```
Package rerunfilecheck Info: Checksums for
```

which comes always in the context like

```
Package rerunfilecheck Info: Checksums for `manualArithInOctave.aux':
(rerunfilecheck)             Before: AE29388CCDAB80FD9099D31C76042CA5;26803
(rerunfilecheck)             After:  3FBBC4F917BC53D0C178CFCE6CA06FBB;26803.
```

and indicates rerun also.

But this is a hack of course.
For sure there is someone out with a better understanding of tex programming
which comes up with a better solution.

A solution would be also to make the compiler not produce a line break at all.

Comment: Should your title be 'how to get rerunfilecheck warning on a single line?'

Comment: you can make the log lines longer or  change the package to add a line break to the message

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ah how can I prolongue the line? Must do it in a controlled way..

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I want to keep the package. because I want that others can use my material without problem.

Comment: @cfr you are right.. I resolved the error in another way.

Comment: @user2609605 if you want others to use it it's probably easier to redefine the message rather than ask users to set the tex line length paramete

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am not the author of the package. 
I am the author of some software checking the output of the package. 
My position is not so strong.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\typeout{Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `manualArithInOctave.aux' has changed. Rerun.}
\end{document}
```

produces

```
Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `manualArithInOctave.aux' has changed. Rer
un.
(./ee4450.aux) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on ee4450.log.
```

but if you set `max_print_line`  in a `texmf.cnf` or on the commandline you can have more than 80 characters:

```
$ pdflatex --cnf-line="max_print_line=100" ee4450
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./ee4450.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01>
L3 programming layer <2023-11-09>
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def) (./ee4450.aux)
Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `manualArithInOctave.aux' has changed. Rerun.
(./ee4450.aux) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on ee4450.log.
```

This applies to all engines, pdftex, xetex luatex, the `--cnf-line` option is for texlive, in miktex use `-max-print-line, as in -max-print-line=100`

---

You did not provide an example, but actually almost all messages from the package provide a line break after the filename, I would guess you used the `aux` option which has a special case to avoid a forced linebreak. The code does

```
            \ifx\\#4\\%
              \space Rerun%
            \else
              \MessageBreak
              #4%
            \fi
```

So if you avoid `[aux]` and instead specify the aux file should be checked with any custom message, you will get a line break before `Rerun`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{rerunfilecheck}
\RerunFileCheck{\jobname.aux}{}{Rerun, see new line}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
% force it to never stabilise so you always get a rerun message
\write\@auxout{\global\c@page=\the\numexpr\c@page+1\relax}
this is page \label{aaa}\pageref{aaa}
\end{document}
```

produces terminal output

```
Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `vvvverrrryyyylonnngnaame.aux' has changed
.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun, see new line.
```

Comment: Wow, very good... I think I can use that.. 
But still better would be to avoid a line break.

Comment: @user2609605 That's what this does, but there was a typo which may have obscured that fact. How can you avoid a break without making the lines longer?

Comment: The command line shown is for TeXLive versions of the software.  For MiKTeX, you instead use the option `-max-print-line`, as in `-max-print-line=100`.

Comment: @JohnCollins ah thanks I'll add the miktex version.

Comment: @user2609605 version forcing a break before rerun added (you should have provided an example in the question as the issue does not arise by default)